# type '_CompactLinkedHashSet<NetworkImage>' is not a subtype of type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Carousel(
 images: [
  for (int cind = 0; cind <posts[index].images.length; cind++){
   new NetworkImage(posts[index].images[cind].image 
}])
```

I am trying to produce a networkimage for every string that is given to my post. Why am i getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Carousel(
 images: posts[index].images.map<Widget>((e)=>NetworkImage(e.image ).toList(),)
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.